# Compare two variance ratios

Tags: variance, repeated-measures

I have paired data from two samples (variables $X_{A1}$ & $X_{A2}$ from sample $A$, and $X_{B1}$ & $X_{B2}$ from sample $B$).

There are lots of methods for comparing the variance of two paired variables (the R package [PairedData](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PairedData/versions/1.1.1) has lots of functions), but how do I test whether the ratios of two sets of paired variables differ? Is $var(X_{A1})/var(X_{A2})$ different from $var(X_{B1}) / var(X_{B2})$?

In other words, is there a way to run a 2-way repeated-measures ANOVA, but with variances instead of means?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone sees this and has the same question, I ended up using an hglm model with a sub-model for dispersion. See the R package '[hglm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hglm/index.html)'. I computed the significance of the correlation with dispersion using blocked permutations generated with the '[permute](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/permute/index.html)' package.